# Invalid memory address page fault handler update

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, interrupt-handling

I am currently trying to update the interrupt handler for page fault in a certain invalid range of memory addresses. The ultimate goal is that we can use our own defined handler instead of default one. There are several ways I am thinking of:

1. Find the IDT (interrupt descriptor table) and update the handler address for page fault in the table. I tried to use inline assembly with "lidt" instruction, but ended up with segfault for that inline assembly.
2. Use userfaultfd to define a user page fault handler, but it seems not to work with an invalid memory address.

Does anyone have some promising suggestions or viable ideas for modifying the interrupt handler in user space? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am using x86_64 on Linux with C btw, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.